# jQuery plugin: fails on re-attaching the plugin itself

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, load, click

I have this html:

```
<div class="item">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="form.php" class="delete">delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="form.php" class="delete">delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="form.php" class="delete">delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When you click on the `delete` button, a form will be loaded to ask you to click **yes** or **no**.

When you click **no** the previous html will be returned.

The problem in this plugin I made below, is that you only can click the `delete` button up to **two** times then the ajax fails to work at the **third** time.

How come? How can resolve this?

You can see this bug on this [link](http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/jquery.plugin.reload.self/).

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").delete_string({targetElement:'.item'});
});

(function($){
    // Attach this new method to jQuery
    $.fn.extend({ 
        // This is where you write your plugin's name
        delete_string: function(options) {
            // Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
            var defaults = {
                targetElement:          '.item-needle',
                targetSlibing:          false
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            // When you create the click function you can assign that element to a variable and reference it within:
            var $cm = this.click(function(e){

                // Set the varible.
                var object = $(this);
                var object_path = object.attr('href');
                var object_parent = object.parents('ul');
                var html_parent = object_parent.html();
                var object_superparent = object.parents(o.targetElement);

                var target_element = object.parents(o.targetElement);
                var target_slibing = target_element.next(o.targetSlibing);
                //alert(target_slibing);

                // Load the form.
                object_parent.load( object_path, function(){

                    // Attach click to the no button.
                    $("input[type=button][name=no]",object_parent).click(function(){

                        // Get the html content back.
                        object_parent.html(html_parent);

                        // Attach the delete plugin back in.
                        $($cm.selector,object_parent).delete_string({targetElement:o.targetElement});
                        return false;

                    });
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The problem come from this line as far as I can find out:

```
$($cm.selector,object_parent).delete_string({targetElement:o.targetElement});
```

it would be fine if I just do this,

```
$($cm.selector).delete_string({targetElement:o.targetElement});
```

but this will attach the `delete plugin` to **all other existing delete button** on the screen, won't it?

Comment: It seems you are deleting the item from the DOM tree, which would mean that after 3 clicks, there is no item left?

Comment: there are more than three items in the real situation. actually that plugin works up to two clicks, it fails on the third click. I have updated the OP. thanks.

Comment: Ah it seems that you are loosing the ajax handler on the element. Not sure why this happens only after 2 clicks, but it seems you might need to re-register the Ajax event ($(".delete")....)

Comment: thanks. can you write a bit more how I can re-register the Ajax event ($(".delete")....)? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here. http://api.jquery.com/live

Comment: Sorry, ran out of ideas, have a look at jEditable plugin. It doesn't similar to what you want to achieve, maybe some hints in there...

Comment: thanks Trefex! will have a look! :-)

Answer (score 0):

When building a plug-in for multiple elements, it is always best to return $.each:

```
(function($){   
    $.fn.delete_string=function(options){
        var defaults={
            targetElement:'.item-needle',
            targetSlibing:false
        },options=$.extend(defaults,options);
        return($(this).each(function(){
            // Build your plug-in here
        }));
    };
})(jQuery);
```